# In Node.js 7 what is the proper way to suppress UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In Node.js I have a module which consists of just one function. The function returns promise and the promise could be rejected. Still I don't want to force all users of the module to handle the rejection explicitly. By design in some cases it makes sense to just ignore the returned promise. Also I don't want to take the ability to handle the promise rejection away from module users.

What is the way to properly do so?

After upgrading to Node.js 7.1.0 all my unit tests which ignore rejection handling show the following warning:

```
(node:12732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: try to throw an error from unit test
(node:12732) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What is the proper way to prevent termination of Node.js process in the future mentioned in `DeprecationWarning` description?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with not handling rejection as long as you're aware that you're doing it, and you have a reason. Ignore the unit tests.

Comment: @adeneo, DeprecationWarning description explicitly say: "In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code." So I'd like to avoid it before it happens. Also, I'd like suppress the warning as I don't want to spam my module users with any irrelevant warnings.

Comment: This is just your unit testing, the correct thing to do would probably be to let your module work like any other module, and let the user deal with his/her own errors, and handle them appropriately, anything else would be unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried handling your rejected promises?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, using a custom library like bluebird you can suppress rejections just from your code but nowhere else. Native promises can't do this yet.

You can however manually suppress a promise by adding a catch handler for it.

```
 function yourExportedFunction() {
     const p = promiseThatMightRejectFn(); 
     p.catch(() => {}); // add an empty catch handler
     return p;
 }
```

This way you are *explicitly* ignoring the rejection from the promise so it is no longer an unhandled rejection just a suppressed one.

Comment: As a note to the answer - it is probably better to not do this - either something is an error or it is not. Exceptional errors should not be ignored - you should pass the error to the user without suppressing the warning and let the users choose if it's important or not - they can suppress it on their end just fine.

Comment: I understand that the promise failure can be naively handled with empty catcher. I asked if there is a way to re-establish broken compatibility.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov what broken compatibility?

Comment: `DeprecationWarning` warning says: "In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code." That would be a broken compatibility, since in previous versions of Node.js promises failures can be safely ignored.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov right, and my answer is a future proof way to do that in an API. The `DeprecationWarning` is in regards to promise rejections that are never handled - in my answer the promise rejection _is_ in fact handled by being explicitly suppressed.

Comment: In your answer there is still an incompatibility. Fake `catch(() => {})` prevents users of `yourExportedFunction` from handling exceptions, whereas right now they can do so.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov the user can just add a `.catch(error => handleError(error))` on their side just fine - this answer does not limit that - try it for yourself - we're not altering the original promise.

Comment: That's simply not true. The user's `catch` won't be invoked, as the failure is already handled by fake `catch(() => {})`. I just created a simple test example to check that:
(function f() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject('rejected');
   }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}()).catch(e => console.log('handled'));

Comment: Benjamin is right Volodymyr, he is returning `p` not `p.catch(() => {})`. He essentially forks the promise, but because one fork has a catch the other fork won't trigger a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: @david, Ahh, I didn't noticed that the promise is forked. It looks like what I need.

Comment: This doesn't suppress the rejection: it *handles* it and settles the Promise as `resolved`.

Comment: @NicholasCarey no, it forks the promise and settles _that_ promise, it doesn't do anything to the original promise.

Answer (score 8):

If you're concerned about unhandled rejections causing your Nodejs process to terminate unintentionally in the future, you could register an event handler for the ['unhandledRejection' event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) on the `process` object.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, p) => {
  console.log('An unhandledRejection occurred');
  console.log(`Rejected Promise: ${p}`);
  console.log(`Rejection: ${err}`);
});
```

#### Edit

If you want the implementing user of your module to decide whether or not to handle the error in their code, you should just return your promise to the caller.

**yourModule.js**

```
function increment(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!value)
      return reject(new Error('a value to increment is required'));                  

    return resolve(value++);
  });
}
```

**theirModule.js**

```
const increment = require('./yourModule.js');

increment()
  .then((incremented) => {
    console.log(`Value incremented to ${incremented}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle rejections returned from increment()
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: In `unhandledRejection` event, is there any way to suppress only my promises, and leave all the other promises untouched? I don't want to unnecessary suppress `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` unrelated to my module.

Comment: Not in a straight forward way, this will be registered for any unhandledRejections regardless of module if they are running within the same process. This is because the `process` object is global to all modules running within the same process. You could use a child process if you want a totally separate `process` object.

Comment: I cannot run in a totally separate `process`.

I mean, is there any way to invoke "default behavior" for `unhandledRejection` if I detect that `p` promise doesn't belong to my module?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why having this handler would cause a problem for any modules, it will prevent your process for crashing irrespective of the rejecting promise. As far as "default behavior" what do you mean by that?

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov I've updated my answer to illustrate how to allow code implementing your module to handle any rejections.

Comment: @VolodymyrFrolov there is no way to what you describe since the user can add a second `unhandledRejection` handler (and users do).

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out any way to do what you're describing.

If you don't care about passing errors to your users, you can add a dummy `catch` block on the end of your promise chain:

```
Promise.reject('foo')
.catch(() => {})
```

This will silence the warning, but won't allow your users to handle the error.

Perhaps you could add an option that your users could decide if they want to handle the error or not.

Comment: I care about passing errors to my users. With the dummy `catch` block my users won't be able to handle errors if needed. It's up to my users to decide if it's needed or not.

Comment: I know. I understand the reasons the node.js team would think this behavior is a good idea; but there are some edge cases that they didn't think of.

Comment: Yes, and my module happened to be among these edge cases.

Comment: @RyanZim hi, NodeJS guy here - nice answer. We actually had very lengthy discussion about this and decided that the tradeoffs are well worth it. So far we have received overwhelmingly positive feedback about the addition of these warnings. I'd be interested in hearing about your edge case here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-and-us-election btw. The changes are since node 6.6 and not 7.0 to be precise.

Comment: Two comments about the answer - you can fork a chain (see my answer) and also - never reject with strings since you get no stack traces. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your problem to fix.

Just use promises the way they were intended.  If the end user doesn't want to handle all rejections then THEY have to add an `unhandledRejection` handler. Otherwise they will need to add catches.

If your errors truly aren't breaking then you shouldn't be rejecting on them. Just resolve with an error value. e.g:

Success: `resolve({result, error:null})`

Failure: `resolve({result:null, error})`

It's still better to just reject and leave the end user to decide how to handle it.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your answer. From design point of view it is up to end user to decide if the warning is to be suppressed. I'll add it to my module's documentation.

Comment: BTW, my errors could be truly non-breaking but they could be totally breaking as well. I don't know. It's up to module users to decide.